# Calculate the difference in Hours and Minutes using Javascript and populate results into another field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hoping to have javascript combine the two date and time fields and then subtract the second set of date & time fields so that the solution is populated in the next field.

JS:

```
hours.onblur = function() { 
    var OutDateTimeValue = OutDateField.value + OutTimeField.value; 
    var InDateTimeValue = InDateField.value + InTimeField.value; 
    hours.value = InDateTimeValue - OutDateTimeValue; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td align=\"right\"><b>Date:</b></td>
    <td colspan=\"2\"> <input type=\"text\" id=\"block_out_date\" name=\"block_out_date\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"7\" tabindex=\"2\" /></td>
    <td align=\"right\"><b>Date:</b></td>
    <td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"block_in_date\" name=\"block_in_date\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"7\" tabindex=\"5\" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=\"right\"><b>Out Time:</b></td>
    <td colspan=\"2\"> <input type=\"text\" id=\"block_out_time\" name=\"block_out_time\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"7\" tabindex=\"3\" /></td>
    <td align=\"right\"><b>In Time:</b></td>
    <td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"block_in_time\" name=\"block_in_time\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"7\" tabindex=\"6\" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align=\"right\"><b>Hours:</b></td>
    <td><input type=\"text\" id=\"hours\" name=\"hours\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"7\" tabindex=\"8\" /></td>
    <td align=\"right\"><b>Rate:</b></td>
    <td><input type=\"text\" id=\"rate\" name=\"rate\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"7\" value=\"1.80\" tabindex=\"9\" /></td>
    <td align=\"right\"><b>Amount:</b></td>
    <td><input type=\"text\" id=\"amount\" name=\"amount\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"7\" tabindex=\"10\" /></td>
</tr>
```

If.... the `block_out_date` is `09/03/2018`
and the `block_out_time` is `05:00`
and the `block_in_date` is `09/12/2018`
and the `block_in_time` is `21:17`

Can Javascript populate the Hours field with:
`232:17 (232 hours and 17 minutes)`?

Additionally, can it multiply this value with the rate of`$1.80` and populate the amount field with `$418.11`?

Comment: Short answer is yes to both. Up to you however to do the basic research on how to start this. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is to help fix your code when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: I'm getting a Nan error at the moment. All my attempts have failed.

Comment: Ok..show us what you tried then. That will help you get a lot more assistance

Comment: I acknowledge this is not intended as a free code writing service. Eclipse does not provide me feedback if the syntax is correct, the webpage simply does not respond.  My current code is:   hours.onblur = function() {
   var OutDateTimeValue = OutDateField.value + OutTimeField.value;
   var InDateTimeValue = InDateField.value + InTimeField.value;
   hours.value = InDateTimeValue - OutDateTimeValue;
}

Comment: Please edit the question with the code so it can be formatted and read easily.

Comment: Edited to: Add OP's JS code from comments to body of question, code formatting, typo.

Answer (score 0):

As idea how to do required calculations you can use code below

```js
// calculates total number of minutes between end and start, end > start;
function totalMinutes(start, end) {
  return ((end.valueOf() - start.valueOf()) / 60000 + 0.5) | 0;
}
// convert minutes to text representation hhh:mm
function toHours(m) {
  let hours = (m / 60) | 0;
  let minutes = m % 60;
  return hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? ("0" + minutes) : ("" + minutes));
}

let rate = 1.8;
let minutes = totalMinutes(new Date(2018, 8, 3, 5, 0, 0), new Date(2018, 8, 12, 21, 17, 0));
let amount = minutes / 60 * rate;
let text = toHours(minutes)
console.log("hours: " + text + " | rate: $" + rate + "/hour | amount: $" + amount);
```